# relative parent, absolute child

Tags: css, css-position, absolute, overlapping

just wondering if there is a css only solution / trick to avoid the absolute element overlapping the content below.

I already learned that position absolute takes out the element from the layout so its not possible to give the parent element the height of its absolute child. 
Maybe you guys know a workaround.

thanks for your time and thoughts

```css
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
     color: #222;
     font-size: 50px;

}

/*FadeIn*/
.fadeIn{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 8px;
}
.fadeIn span{
 animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 color: #00abe9;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 10s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*FadeIn Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  
  <h2 class="sentence">
    <div class="fadeIn">
      <span>Handsome.</span>
      <span>Clean.</span>
      <span>Elegant.</span>
      <span>Magnificent.</span>
      <span>Adorable.</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
  <h2>LOrem iaoeg egaa eg aeg aeg aegoaegaokeg aeogk aeogkae gok </h2>
 

</body>
```

As soon as I add a letter it works. So maybe adding a pseudo element is a solution?

```css
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
     color: #222;
     font-size: 50px;

}

/*FadeIn*/
.fadeIn{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 8px;
}
.fadeIn span{
 animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 color: #00abe9;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 10s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*FadeIn Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  
  <h2 class="sentence">A
    <div class="fadeIn">
      <span>Handsome.</span>
      <span>Clean.</span>
      <span>Elegant.</span>
      <span>Magnificent.</span>
      <span>Adorable.</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
  <h2>LOrem iaoeg egaa eg aeg aeg aegoaegaokeg aeogk aeogkae gok </h2>
 

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `.fadeIn` element now has no non-absolute children, so basically it has a height of 0 because absolute elements don't get calculated in the height of their parent.

Thus, the only thing you need to do is giving a proper `height` to `.fadeIn` element.

There are many ways you can handle that, but I made this one for you. I'm going to make `:first-child` of your `span`s inside of `.fadeIn` element as `position: static` ( default position value ) to let its parent know how much `height` should it take.

The other way is to set `height: 50px` ( for example ) for you `.fadeIn` element to let that element know how much should it take as height.

The other way ( as you already mentioned ) is to make another child ( in your example, an *A* ) to let it know the height value.

and many more ways.

But I've taken the first solution ( there were some other changes according to that context to make sure everything's working properly ). Look at the following code:

```css
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
  color: #222;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.fadeIn { position: relative; }

.fadeIn span{
 animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 color: #00abe9;
 opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.fadeIn span:first-child { position: static; display: block }
.fadeIn span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.fadeIn span:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 10s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*FadeIn Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadeEffect{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  
  <h2 class="sentence">
    <div class="fadeIn">
      <span>Handsome.</span>
      <span>Clean.</span>
      <span>Elegant.</span>
      <span>Magnificent.</span>
      <span>Adorable.</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
  <h2>LOrem iaoeg egaa eg aeg aeg aegoaegaokeg aeogk aeogkae gok </h2>
 

</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't make all the elements to be `absolute`. Keep one `relative` (or `static`) so it allocate the needed space:

```css
/*Sentence*/

.sentence {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 50px;
}


/*FadeIn*/

.fadeIn {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 8px;
  position: relative;/*added*/
}

.fadeIn span {
  animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #00abe9;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /*added*/
  top: 0; /*added*/
}


/*added this*/
.fadeIn span:first-child {
  position: relative;
}
/**/

.fadeIn span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.fadeIn span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.fadeIn span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.fadeIn span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}


/*FadeIn Animation*/

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="sentence">
  <div class="fadeIn">
    <span>Handsome.</span>
    <span>Clean.</span>
    <span>Elegant.</span>
    <span>Magnificent.</span>
    <span>Adorable.</span>
  </div>
</h2>
<h2>LOrem iaoeg egaa eg aeg aeg aegoaegaokeg aeogk aeogkae gok </h2>
```